# How to find the parent of a node in Left Child Right Sibling Tree?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

I want to find the parent of a node N in a Left Child Right Sibling Tree. The tree has ordered children and there's no limit for the number of children.

```
Node getParent(Node n)
{
   ....
   return parent;
}
```

I really need help, because there's no direct way to find it.

The answer can be in pseudo-code or a programming language.

Comment: You know the node you're trying to find the parent of right? Now if you have a parent reference, which IMHO you should, `find()` the node and it's all gravy from there.

Comment: no i dont have a parent reference, its for a homework, and i cant change that... So i have to find the parent, just knowing the tree's root

Comment: No, i just know that children are always ordered...

Comment: So, find the node where the child node is "current node".

Comment: You basically then need to start at the root and work your way back down the tree until the next appropriate node is the node that called the method, then return a reference to the current node.

Comment: Recursively traverse the tree with a helper function which either returns sth like `null` or the found parent.

Comment: Is the tree in an array?

Answer (score 0):

Starting at the root, search remembering the last time you took a left branch. When you find the key, the node from which you took the last left was the parent node. If there was no left branch taken, then there is no parent.

BTW, In the [Wikipedia definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-child_right-sibling_binary_tree)

> a left-child, right-sibling binary tree is a binary tree representation of a k-ary tree.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-child_right-sibling_binary_tree) The process of converting from a k-ary tree to an LC-RS binary tree (sometimes called Knuth transform[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3aLeft_child-right_sibling_binary_tree)) is not reversible in general without additional information.

The phrase *is not reversible in general without additional information* implies that what you are trying to do is impossible. But I disagree, and so does [this Wikipedia discussion page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3aLeft_child-right_sibling_binary_tree)

Comment: Whether or not the transform is reversible, the node clearly has a unique parent. If it didn't have a parent, it wouldn't be in the tree. If it has more than one parent, then the data structure is not a tree.

Comment: Well, sure, every node other than the root has a parent; the question is: can it be identified? If it can always be identified, then the original tree can always be reconstructed, and the transform reversed, i,e, the Wikipedia article would be incorrect.

Comment: On reflection, in this context, I believe the article is wrong (my "you can try this" is correct).I'm editing my answer to refkect that. This sheds further light on it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ALeft_child-right_sibling_binary_tree

Comment: Yeah, that discussion is bogus. "If you cannot distinguish left from right, then the process is not reversible." But of course you can distinguish left from right. If you couldn't, then it wouldn't be called a "left-child right-sibling tree"; it would be called a "child and sibling mixed together tree".

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer not tested with many cases though but you can get the idea

```
struct node{
    node* left;
    node* right;
    int i;

    node(int _i,node* _left,node* _right){
        i=_i;
        left = _left;
        right = _right;
    }
};

node* traverse(node* root,node* parent, int y){
    if(root == NULL) return NULL;
    if(root->i == y) return parent;

    node* result  = traverse(root->left,root,y);
    if(result) return result;

    result = traverse(root->right, parent , y);
    if(result) return result;

    return NULL;

}
```

The traverse function is called like

```
 traverse(rootofthistree, NULL, integerWearlookingfor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I understand your data structure:

- `node.left` is one of:

  - previous sibling (if `node` is not first sibling)
  - parent (if `node` is first sibling)
  - `null` (if `node` is the tree root)
- `node.right` is one of:

  - next sibling (if `node` is not last sibling)
  - `null` (if `node` is the last sibling)
- `node.child` is one of:

  - the first child (if `node` has any children)
  - `null` (if `node` is a tree leaf)

You can then get the parent of a node `N` by the following algorithm:

```
node* get_parent(node* N)
{
    //define parent of nullptr to be nullptr
    if (!N)
        return nullptr;
    while (true)
    {
        if (N->left)
        {
            //N->left is either the previous sibling or the parent
            if (N->left->child == N) //N->left is the parent
                return N->left;
            else //N->left is the previous sibling
                N = N->left;
        }
        else //a node with left==nullptr is the root, so its parent is nullptr
        {
            return nullptr;
        }
    }
}
```